# Creating a dashboard for the last branch deployed through pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I want to create at-a-glance visibility of what was most recently deployed. I tried the deployment status widget but we don't use release pipelines so it doesn't work for us https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#deployment-status-widget.

I tried reviewing the rest of the catalog but nothing seems to fit. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome! I don't follow, what exactly is missing so that the deployment widget isn't enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are talking about YAML pipeline. The `Release Pipeline Overview` widget you can use to view and track the status of a release pipeline. This widget shows the release as a series of environments, with the name of the release and the date or time it was started. So currently it doesn’t support to view and track the status of a YAML pipeline.

Unfortunately, there is no out-of-the-box widgets to view the deployment status in YAML pipelines. However, there is already a user voice in our official feature suggestion website, you can follow the suggestion and vote it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1015212/ado-dashboard-widget-release-pipeline-overview-sho.html

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?